# Access files outside/below public_html level

Tags: php, web-services, hosting, web-hosting

How can I access files via a url that are placed in `/home/uzair/etc/index.php`? Even when I run domain (`something.com`) it shows me data of (`/home/uzair/public_html/index.php`) this file.

Anyone please help me that how can I access that placed in (`/home/uzair/etc/index.php`) on my domain (`something.com`)

- home

  - uzair

    - etc

      - index.php
    - public_html

      - admin
      - index.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you are in `something.com` which is visible to you on the web so it is located inside of `public_html` but you want to include a file that is higher up in the file system.

If that is what you are looking to do, use:

```
include("../etc/index.php");
```

The `..` tells the server that you want to access the files in the next level up.

If you did:

```
include("../../uzair/etc/index.php");
```

That would have taken you all the way up to `home` and from there you would have access to many more files if you wanted to.

Files outside of public_html are protected from being seen on the web. Many people use that feature as a security to their content. If you have a file on there that you want to show contents of though, you have to use the include('file.php'); or include_once('file.php'); or even require_once('file.php') in a public ally visible file. Aka a file you have in public_html has to be the one to call the higher up file. If I am understanding your question right, that is how it is supposed to be done. Let me know if that is answering your question or not:-)

**How you can run files not in `public_html`?**

Files outside of public_html are protected from being seen on the web. Many people use that feature as a security to their content. If you have a file on there that you want to show contents of though, you have to use the `include('file.php');` or `include_once('file.php');` or even `require_once('file.php')` in a public ally visible file. Aka a file you have in `public_html` has to be the one to call the higher up file. If I am understanding your question right, that is how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: how can i run `/home/uzair/etc/index.php` this file directly from domain?? is there any possible way??? like `somthing.com/../etc/index.php` basically i wana run directly this file.

Comment: Files outside of public_html are protected from being seen on the web. Many people use that feature as a security to their content. If you have a file on there that you want to show contents of though, you have to use the include('file.php'); or include_once('file.php'); or even require_once('file.php') in a public ally visible file. Aka a file you have in public_html has to be the one to call the higher up file. If I am understanding your question right, that is how it is supposed to be done.  Let me know if that is answering your question or not:-)

Comment: @tylerlindell , I have a question -- My `index.php` is inside of the wwwroot folder, and my `other.php` is inside of a folder just outside of wwwroot. How do I access `other.php`?