# where to store my sensitive files in cPanel?

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a website that uses PHP and runs on Cpanel.
I have some .xls and.pdf files that I want only for my customers who have an account to be able to download, and I also have some .json and .csv files that I only use in the backend (via PHP code) and I don't want anyone to be able to download them.

Can I upload everything to the public_html and store them in unguessable directories like "/0909278348734873847/file.json"? does it do the job?
Should I upload things outside of public_html? can I then access them via PHP?
or is it something else?
thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: You may refer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187712/access-files-outside-below-public-html-level

Answer (score 1):

.You can place the sensitive file outside public_html.Files outside of public_html are protected from being seen on the web. Many people use that feature as a security to their content. If you have a file on there that you want to show contents of though, you have to use the include('data.php'); or include_once('data.php'); or even require_once('data.php') in a public ally visible file. ie, a file you have in public_html has to be the one to call the higher up file. By this you can programatically control the access to sensitive data

Comment: great, but what about the excel files I want my users to be able to download? how can I achieve that?